# Disabling triple tap on android devices

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I am making a game on android devices, and with android 4.2 and the accessibility magnifier on, my game keeps zooming in and out. Is there a way to disable it on the application.xml file? I develop my game with AIR.

Thanks a lot!

Yvan

Comment: preventDefault or stop propagation maybe?

Comment: have you set stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE ?

Comment: If it's possible to disable it in a per-application basis, you should be able to do it with a Native Extension (ANE). The idea is that you write native code (Java I think?) then you compile it in an ANE file, and then you can use native features from your Adobe Air application.

Comment: Actually, the problem isn't only about the magnification. Having the triple tap activated, the os waits for a little while in order to recognize a tap as a single tap. So the preventDefault (if doable with a triple tap) and the stage.scaleMode won't work. As for the ANE solution, do you have some links / documentation? I was hoping for a solution directly on the configuration file, but I don't know if it's possible...